# physical address that pinned by get_user_pages_fast is not accessible

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, mapping, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a Linux kernel driver that pins a user memory in the kernel space and return the physical address, This is done by using the function get_user_pages_fast.

I checked it on a several different kernel versions and I found an issue on a very specific machine - the physical address is not accessible.

I can fix it by modifying the intel_iommu parameter (in /boot/grub2/grub.cfg) from 'on' to 'off' but in all the machines that I tested this flow, the inter_iommu was 'on'

What mechanism is hiding behind the intel_iommu? I believe that this parameter is not the root cause.

What can be the root cause?

Comment: What do you mean by "not accessible"? Do you mean that `get_user_pages_fast` is returning an error?

Comment: @IanAbbott this function is not returning an error. I got a physical address but I cannot work with it: failed to read this address using another tool / fw tried to access but not succeed.